# Using Applescript in Automator app to run ffmpeg

Tags: applescript

ffmpeg runs exactly like I want it to.  I'm sure the following is not super clean but it does work with one exception: it simply adds the .mp4 to the original filename so that the new filename appears to have two extensions.

I've spent days searching for similar problems on multiple forums with no real help.  I've tried copying and pasting suggestions with different errors.  I would really like to drag a video file onto this applet and have it run ffmpeg the way I've specified in the shell portion with the resulting output file being created in the location of the input file but with a different extension.

I've tried the "filesString" way and the \"f\" + "{$f%.*}" and for whatever reason that doesn't seem to do anything but open terminal with the text of the shell.  Other options result in a message stating that there's "NO SUITABLE OUTPUT" which I have finally figured out means, "whatever you're doing is great, but I'm going to give you this error until you take the spaces out of your file name/folders."

So:

1. To drop a file and have it convert to file with the standards specified. (check)
2. Have that output file go back to the folder where the input file lives. (check)
3. But with only the new extension. (fail)
4. A bonus would be to edit the script such that I could drop a folder of files onto the applet and have them convert 1 at a time.  I believe I can drop a folder at this time but then it opens multiple instances of Terminal and processes simultaneously.  I'd like to have the files process 1 at a time.

---

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with file_ in input
        tell application "System Events"
            set inputFilename to name of (get properties of file_)
        end tell
        set inputFilePath to quoted form of (POSIX path of file_)
        set outputFilePath to quoted form of (POSIX path of file_)
        tell application "Terminal"
            activate
            do script "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/bin/ffmpeg -i " & inputFilePath & " -aspect 4:3 -vf yadif=0:-1:0,scale=720:486 -acodec libfdk_aac -cutoff 20000 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv420p " & outputFilePath & ".mp4"
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

Comment: I've edited your post as it was strung together and the _code_ what not properly displayed. That said, you should also add the layout of your Automator App's i.e., actions/settings etc. Additionally clarify what you're trying to say in number 4.  As to number 3, that's easily fixed and I'll post an answer of it shortly.

Answer (score 3):

This takes care of number 3, the double file extension issue.

I've modified the *code* below from your original *code* in the following ways:

Added the `remove_extension(this_name)` *subroutine* from the bottom of the [Essential Sub-routines](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/index.html) page.

Changed:

```
set outputFilePath to quoted form of (POSIX path of file_)
```

To:

```
set outputFilePath to quoted form of (my remove_extension(POSIX path of file_) & ".mp4")
```

Removed `& ".mp4"` from the end of the `do script ...` line.

I then tested it on an actual `.mkv` file and while the process started, nonetheless I did stop it shortly there after, as it was just a test to see the original `filename.mkv` was writing to `filename.mp4`, and it was.

```
on remove_extension(this_name)
    if this_name contains "." then
        set this_name to (the reverse of every character of this_name) as string
        set x to the offset of "." in this_name
        set this_name to (text (x + 1) thru -1 of this_name)
        set this_name to (the reverse of every character of this_name) as string
    end if
    return this_name
end remove_extension

on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with file_ in input
        tell application "System Events"
            set inputFilename to name of (get properties of file_)
        end tell
        set inputFilePath to quoted form of (POSIX path of file_)
        set outputFilePath to quoted form of (my remove_extension(POSIX path of file_) & ".mp4")
        tell application "Terminal"
            activate
            do script "/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/bin/ffmpeg -i " & inputFilePath & " -aspect 4:3 -vf yadif=0:-1:0,scale=720:486 -acodec libfdk_aac -cutoff 20000 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv420p " & outputFilePath
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

---

If you want to use the `AppleScript's text item delimiters` *method*, wrapped in a *subroutine*, then replace the existing `on remove_extension(this_name)` *subroutine* with the following one, while leaving the others changes I made to your *code* as I did.

```
on remove_extension(this_name)
    try
        set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"."}
        if number of text items of this_name > 1 then
            set this_name to (text items 1 thru -2 of this_name as text)
        end if
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
    on error
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelims
    end try
    return this_name
end remove_extension
```

This is essentially doing the same as the original `on remove_extension(this_name)` *subroutine* I first used, it's just a different method using what was mentioned in user14492's answer, only presented in what I'd consider to be a more proper form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set posixPath to (POSIX path of file_)
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
if number of text items of posixPath > 1 then
    set outputFilePath to quoted form of (text items 1 thru -2 of posixPath as text)
end if
```

More about [text delimiter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24422).

To add folder support, try something like this:

```
#First check if it's folder
set mp4Files to every file of inputFolder whose name extension is "mp4"
```